# Basic boilerplate with Koajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, koa

I'm very new to Koajs (http://koajs.com/) but i've used Express quite a bit. As the team behind Express made Koa I wanted to try it.

When i'm starting a new express project all I need to type is `express projectname` or even just `express`

With koajs, is there a way I can simply type a command in like that to setup a quick, boilerplate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Koa doesn't have what you're asking for.  I'd suggest looking at the koa wiki page, there are several boilerplates listed there that you could clone.

https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki#frameworks

Answer (score 1):

I had built a sample project for KoaJS that contains some configuration for quick starting, building with Babel ES6, routing, doing middleware, you can clone and modify as your project requirement. 
try [koa-starter-kit](https://github.com/nhtua/koa-starter-kit) here!

Comment: Lightly opinionated + includes examples = good start. Well done. A template engine "would be nice", but that would be an opinion, wouldn't it?

Comment: @monsto currently it doesn't have template engine. I supposed it be a RESTful API server, so I just gave it JSON ability as default.

Comment: Right. "lightly opinionated" (=

Answer (score 0):

Here there is an up-to-date well-documented boilerplate to start a REST API with KOA2 and Typescript :)

[node-typescript-koa-rest](https://github.com/javieraviles/node-typescript-koa-rest)